# How can I sort chosen collection in multidimensional array in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

i want to sort by **cu_customer_shortname** in nested array collection but seems i cant see any ways do it . here is my example of my array list

```
{#1811 ▼
  +"co_group_id": "ADUKO"
  +"co_description": "ADUKO"
  +"co_customer_id": "038"
  +"co_active_sts": "1"
  +"irel__h_d_rel_group_customer": array:3 [▼
    0 => {#1812 ▼
      +"ID": "5"
      +"gc_group_id": "ADUKO"
      +"gc_customer_id": "038"
      +"irel__h_d_customer_master": {#1813 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#1814 ▼
      +"ID": "6"
      +"gc_group_id": "ADUKO"
      +"gc_customer_id": "044"
      +"irel__h_d_customer_master": {#1815 ▼
        +"cu_customer_ID": "044"
        +"cu_customer_Shortname": "JPEN"     <------ Sort this shortname
      }
    }
  ]
```

Here is my code that i already tried

```
$groupList  = $contents->data->groupList;
$order      = $groupList->irel__h_d_rel_group_customer; //arrayList
$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($groupList); //collection
$sorted     = $collection->SortByDesc('irel__h_d_customer_master.cu_customer_Shortname'); // sorted by cu_customer_shortname
```

My code not return any error but my list remain and not sorted by **cu_customer_Shortname**

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826730/laravel-orderby-nested-object-in-collection

Comment: @GiacomoM thanks for reached but i got another sub array which is a different approach with the post that u given

Comment: can you can post the final result what the sort should do.

Comment: @AbuPower the approach is the same, just navigate the subarray inside the closure function